# Changing h- text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text of a h2.
If I use alert, it shows undefined with .html and .val, so, wouldn't it be something like this?:

`$("#h2Id").text("new text");`

It doesn't work, though.
Thanks in advance.

edit:
the html is plain simple, as I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testingStuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="question"> ASD </h2>
</body>
```

Comment: Post your HTML. `.text()` is the right way to do it.

Comment: You sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I recommend to read the jQuery help, to learn how to set up your code properly: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: I'm new in programming, but I have already done things with jQuery. More complex things than just changing the text of something. But I just can't find the problem with h- tags :/
And I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The problem isn't any of the ones displayed there.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Unless you show your jquery code to us, I'm going to assume you're literally trying to do `$("#h2Id").text("new text");` when your h2 id is `question` and not `h2Id`.

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure jQuery is loaded.
2. Use the document-ready incantation to let your script wait until the DOM is ready.

   ```
   $(function() {
       $("#h2Id").text("new text");
   });
   ```
3. http://jsfiddle.net is a wonderful resource for quickly mocking up pages and finding problems.

Comment: *"to let your script wait until jQuery is ready."* That's not the purpose, jQuery is ready once it's loaded. This is to wait until all DOM elements are available.

Comment: 1.JQuery is loaded.
2.Even if I use $(document).ready(), it doesn't work.
3.Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4jmEx/

```html
<span id="h2Id">Foo</span>
```

```js
$('#h2Id').text('Bar');
```